# Page loads too slow when serving images from dropbox account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dropbox

I am using dropbox to host my images for my rails app deployed on heroku, but when i request a page it just hangs up for way too long and doesn't responds. Because it waits for GET request for all images which BTW takes way too long and till then page just freeze.

User thinks that nothing is happening and leaves the page.

http://www.shaktimarble.com/makrana_marbles/albeta_marble

I need an opinion how to make this app a bit faster or at least load the page first to make it visible and then load the images on the page so that user doesn't think that nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put those images on a CDN (Content Delivery Network). DropBox really isn't a CDN. It's a file syncing and sharing service. I'd almost be willing to bet that DropBox rate-limits downloads from a single IP address.

Having said all that, you could use JavaScript to load image elements into the DIVs in your page after the page text has rendered, and that might give the illusion that things are a little faster, although the page wouldn't work if the user disables JavaScript.

Comment: hmmm Seems sensible i am using dropbox because its free and convenient to upload using carrierwave.. can u suggest any such CDN service that is free and easy to use with rails app... BTW thanks for response..

Comment: I'm pretty sure DropBox puts a fairly low cap on downloads from free accounts, too. ;-)  You might check out CloudFlare, free for basic use, pay for more advanced features. The way it works is that you have them manage your DNS (instead of GoDaddy or whoever), and then flag the hosts that you want cached. CloudFlare then intelligently serves requests to those hosts from their own servers, calling through to your servers as necessary. You would probably just serve the images off your own server in this case, too, and let CloudFlare cache those.

Comment: Or search for something like "free cdn for images" and see what turns up. I got quite a few hits. Many are free for limited use, then you pay for "professional" traffic levels.

Comment: Thanks buddy I googled a lot and found an awesome hosting service way better than dropbox https://cloudinary.com/ its lightning fast and solves my every purpose...